# Use Firebase SDK in Katalon-Studio

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, katalon-studio

I'm trying to test my website's sign up process.
In the end of the test I want to delete the dummy user that was created during the test from my database (I'm using Firebase).
I use Katalon-Studio to run my test.
I got the following code from some firebase SDK tutorial:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
  new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-name.firebaseio.com")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

The issue is that the compiler can't resolve Firebase's methods/classes. 
I could use a jar file of the required library but I don't know where to get it from. 
What should I do?

Comment: Please add your update as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the jar files here:
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.firebase
I added them as external libraries in katalon (Project->Settings->External Libraries)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so, import the `com.google.firebase.auth.UserRecord` as well as `import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth` libraries into your project.

I used the following to delete a user, they only needed an email address for authentication.

`UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUserByEmail(email);
        String uid = userRecord.getUid()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(uid);`